# Can't use rstrip() inside f-string python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using an f-string to print some values around double quotes:

```py
f.write(f'"{str(ID).rstrip("'")}", "{str(TSQ)}" \n')
```

The problem is that because of the `"'"` rstrip argument, I receive a `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

I know that there are easy fixes available, such as using `.format()` or doing the processing on the `ID` string beforehand, but as using f-strings is generally more pythonic I was wondering if there was a workaround for this.

If ID was 872' and TSQ was 8, this code should print:

`"872", "8"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that you have a quote inside a quote. Use triple surrounding quotes for disambiguation:

```
f'''"{str(ID).rstrip("'")}", "{str(TSQ)}" \n'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape in a true way. Error is not about rstrip but about escaping.

```
f.write(f"\"{str(ID).rstrip(chr(39))}\", \"{str(TSQ)}\" \n")
```